# Excel / Powershell - Export values from a specific column starting from a specific row

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm new to Powershell programming and I have been tasked with exporting email addresses from column 3 in Excel to notepad using Powershell. But the requirement is that I have to start from a specific row. Here's a sample data/script (taken from Steve Fenton - Thanks for the basis Steve!!!!).

If a user inputs Apple (from the read-host prompt), I want to only export the Apple rows' email addresses to notepad (john@email.com and jill@email.com).

Any suggestion/assistance is greatly appreciated!!!! Thank you!!!

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Cg9K.jpg)

```html
 {
    $sourceFile = "C:\Temp\data.xlsx"
    $outFile = "C:\Temp\data.txt"

    $stock = Read-Host -Prompt "Which stock?"

    $startRow = (depends on input from user)
    $col = 3

    $usedCellType = 11

    $excelApp = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 

    try {
        $excelApp.visible = $false;
        $excelApp.DisplayAlerts = $false 

        $workbook = $excelApp.Workbooks.Open($sourceFile) 
        $worksheet = $workbook.ActiveSheet
        $endRow = $worksheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells($usedCellType).Row

        $rangeAddress = $worksheet.Cells.Item($startRow, $col).Address() + ":" + $worksheet.Cells.Item($endRow, $col).Address()
        Write-Host "Using range $($rangeAddress)"

        $worksheet.Range($rangeAddress).Value2 | Out-File -FilePath $outFile
        $workbook.Close($false) 
    }
    finally {
        $excelApp.Quit()
    }
}
```

Comment: Then how about setting `$startRow` to the row number you have to start with?

Comment: Hi Theo. The $startRow depends on the user input. I have modified the script to make that a variable. I just need a loop now to go thru that column to find that "specific value" - until its done searching. Not sure where to put that loop.